# Divide monthly spend into daily spend in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have monthly data in BigQuery in the following form:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS spend (
  id int,
  created_at DATE,
  value float
);

INSERT INTO spend VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', 100),
(2, '2020-02-01', 200),
(3, '2020-03-01', 100),
(4, '2020-04-01', 100),
(5, '2020-05-01', 50);
```

I would like a query to translate it into daily data in the following day:

- One row per day.
- The value of each day should be the monthly value divided by the number of days of the month.

What's the simplest way of doing this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) in order to get an array between the desired dates (in your case, between 2020-01-01 and 2020-05-31) and create a calendar table, and then divide the value of a given month among the days in the month :)

Try this and let me know if it worked:

```
with calendar_table as (
  select
    calendar_date
  from
    unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', '2020-05-31', interval 1 day)) as calendar_date
),
final as (
  select
    ct.calendar_date,
    s.value,
    s.value / extract(day from last_day(ct.calendar_date)) as daily_value
  from 
    spend as s
  cross join 
    calendar_table as ct
  where
    format_date('%Y-%m', date(ct.calendar_date)) = format_date('%Y-%m', date(s.created_at))
)
select * from final
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to do this "locally".  That is, run `generate_date_array()` for each row in the original table.  This is much faster than a `join` across rows.  BigQuery also makes this easy with the `last_day()` function:

```
select t.id, u.date, 
       t.value / extract(day from last_day(t.created_at))
from `table` t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.created_at, 
                                last_day(t.created_at, month)
                               )
           ) u(date);
```